# python else if and equality test

Tags: python

I cannot figure out in python language
why the following code shows an error.

The two codes both show an error, for
me, them really do the same function.

```
     else if(sentenceSplitted[0] == 'What'):
```

Next is different way for the same "function".

```
     else if(sentenceSplitted[-1] == '?'):
```

Answer (score 2):

Python has no `else if`. You should use [`elif`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html).